# How can I get the GPS traces within a region from OpenStreetMap (OSM)?

Tags: open-source, openstreetmap

[The link to download the GPS traces on OSM is quite easy to get.](http://planet.openstreetmap.org/gps/)

However, each of the files inside is all super big. And also there is no geolocation categorization. So I suppose the data inside can be the GPS traces from any part of the world.

What if I **just need the GPS traces within ONE location**, say Boston city? How can I get that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The (editing) [API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6) supports a [query for retrieving GPS traces](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6#GPS_traces) in a given area. Each *page* returns a maximum of *5,000* points so you may have to make several calls for retrieving all of them.

Don't forget to read the [terms of use](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API#Terms_of_use) and the [usage policy](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_usage_policy). This API is not suited for running bulk queries!

If you don't know the bounding box of the city you want to query, you can use [Nominatim](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) to geolocate it.

Comment: so its not like just downloading a file from the site? Where should I use the API?

Comment: Yes it is like downloading a file, see the examples mentioned there. Just call the given URL after inserting the parameters and your browser will present you a GPX file to download.

Answer (score 5):

Alternativelly to using the API (see answer by scai) one could also use an Application like [JOSM](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JOSM) to download the GPX traces.

Comment: True. JOSM is a nice an easy way to *interactively* download traces or map data for a specific area.

Comment: This is an excellent suggestion. JOSM turned out to be really useful.